# Can APC interrupt WSAWaitForMultipleEvents?

Tags: c++, winapi, apc

Can APC (Asynchronous Procedure Calls) interrupt WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()? (C++)

MSDN does not list this WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() on the APC page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681951.aspx ).

I do not have visual studio in front of me right now to try it.

Can somebody please let me know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, the documentation for WSAWaitForMultipleEvents (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742219.aspx) indicates it can be put into an alertable state; it also says that the current implementation calls WaitForMultipleObjectsEx (one of the explicit APC functions), so the answer is yes.